# Extract values from Postgres JSONB column

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column called `metrics` in a table `events`. It stores various metrics as a flat hash, e.g.

```
{"m1": 123, "m2": 122.3, "m3": 32}
```

I would like to extract all the *values* stored in that column. Is it possible? I have found a function `jsonb_object_keys(jsonb)`, but I failed to find anything similar for values.

Comment: There are a few [json & jsonb functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) available for that purpose. Which one to choose depends on your particular case.

Comment: Thanks,  I would like to calculate min value of this json and select all records that has min above some threshold. I tried functions you linked but I failed to achieve what I want. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jsonb_each()` in a lateral join:

```
with val as (
    select '{"m1": 123, "m2": 122.3, "m3": 32}'::jsonb js
    )
select key, value
from val,
lateral jsonb_each(js);

 key | value 
-----+-------
 m1  | 123
 m2  | 122.3
 m3  | 32
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`jsonb_each()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) for this purpose:

```
WITH json_test(data) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"m1": 123, "m2": 122.3, "m3": 32}'::JSONB)
)
SELECT element.value 
FROM json_test jt, jsonb_each(jt.data) as element;
```

Output:

```
 value 
-------
 123
 122.3
 32
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [json_each](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) you can extract the values with:

```sql
SELECT value FROM json_each('{"m1": 123, "m2": 122.3, "m3": 32}')
```

Output

```
value
-----
123
122.3
32
```